# Netty: getting remote ip address in messageReceived

Tags: java, networking, ip, netty

In my class (extends SimpleChannelHandler) I'm trying to get the ip where the message was originally sent from.

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent ev) throws Exception {
    String host = ((InetSocketAddress)ctx.getChannel().getRemoteAddress()).getAddress().getHostAddress();
    int port = ((InetSocketAddress)ctx.getChannel().getRemoteAddress()).getPort();
    LOG.debug(String.format("host:%s port:%d", host, port));

    ..
```

This prints ip 10.0.0.1 (gateway), instead of the correct client address (10.52.45.4).

Is there any way to get the ip i'm trying to or could there be something wrong with the network configuration ?

Comment: Just a slight update in the syntax with newer netty 4.1.5 `((InetSocketAddress )ctx.channel().remoteAddress()).getAddress().getHostAddress();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you see the gateway ip because the gateway does some kind of NAT. If so, the only chance you have is to include the source-ip address in your protocol and extract it from there.

Comment: That seems to be the case. I decided it's better to do as you suggested and included the source-ip (or id in this case) in the protocol. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ip addresses starting with 10.0.0 are internal, you are probably connecting it to something on the same WiFi router. To get the 10.52.45.4 ip, you have to connect outside of your router. (don't forget to port forward)